# 3 select in a form with Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, select

(sorry for my english...)

I need your help for my 3 selects in one form.

Select 1: I choose Pays
Select 2: I choose Regions who depend for the Pays
Select 3 : I choose Towns who depends Region

Actually I use javascript in Twig template to have options in the different select, but when I submit the Form, I doesn't have a value for the ville parameter in my object.

Here is my code for ville in the Form:

```
            ->add('ville', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Ville:',
            'required' => true,
        ])
```

[dd($partenaire)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpdpb.png)
[console detail select after query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyUT8.png)

I have do with EntityType, but this load all the table...

Can someone help me ?
Tanks

Comment: Are you giving the good name in the `select` input ? Can you show us your Javascript code to managed your `select` ?

Comment: Sorry who can I format the code ?  function fetchDataVilles() {
            let ville = selectDepartement.value;
           
   
            let optionsVilles = '<option value="">Choisir une ville...</option>';
            const response = await fetch('/admin/partenaire/recherche/ville/'+ville+'/');
            const data = await response.json();

            console.log(data);

            data.forEach(element => 
                optionsVilles += '<option value="">'+element.name+'</option>'
            )
          
            selectVille.innerHTML = optionsVilles;
        }

Comment: What the name of the select for the ville ?

Comment: @jean-max: partenaire[ville]

Comment: And if you dump the request data in your controller what did you get ?

Comment: Look a the image name dd($partenaire) that is the data after form submit, is it that you want ?

Comment: No dump the `Request $request` in your Controller when you send all correctly filled pls :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add 2 new routes which return html, specifically the select HTML element with the data from the selected parent, ex:

```
#[Route('/regions-select', name: 'regions_select', methods: ['GET'])]
public function getRegionsSelect(Request $request): Response
{
  $entity = new Entity();
  $form = $this->createForm(
     FooFormType::class,
     $entity,
     ['pay' => $request->query->get('pay')]
  );

  return $this->render('_regions-select.html.twig', [
     'form' => $form->createView(),
  ]);
}
```

Then the Form can look like this:

```
$builder
     ->add('district', EntityType::class, [
        'placeholder' => 'Select Pay',
        'label_attr' => ['class' => 'mb-0 d-block'],
        'class' => Pay::class,
        'choice_value' => 'id',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
     ])
     ->add('region', EntityType::class, [
       'class' => Region::class,
       'query_builder' => function (RegionRepository $regionRepository) use ($options) {
              return $regionRepository->regionsByPay((int) $options['pay']);
       },
       'choice_label' => 'name',
       'choice_value' => 'id'
]);
```

You can create the twig file to render the form row for the regions select '_regions-select.html.twig':

```
{{ form_row(form.region, {
    attr: {
        'class': 'mb-3 form-control'
    }
}) }}
```

And you can achieve this by listening to the change event or select event on the Pays dropdown via javascript like this:

```
$paySelect.on('change', (event) => {
  const payId = event.target.value;
  $.ajax({
      url: BASE_URL+'/regions-select',
      data: {
        pay: payId,
      },
      success: function (html) {
        const region = REGION_SELECT_FROM_CLASS_NAME //replace this with your jQuery/Javascript selector;
        region.html($(html).find("option"));
        region.val("").trigger("change");
      },
    });
});
```